# Help with a pseudo-class, first-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am working on a CMS platform with limited access to the template files and want to try and control some of the layout with pseudo class but no luck yet.  Can anyone see what is wrong with this structure and why my pseudo class is being ignored?

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="someRandomDiv"></div>
    <div class="block">
    stuff
    </div>
    <div class="block">
     more stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

and i am trying something like this

```
#main .block {border: 1px solid blue}
#main .block:first-child {border: 1px solid red}
```

so with this example I would think the stuff block would have a red border and more stuff would have a blue but it is all just blue.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not being ignored, there just aren't any matches :)

I realize it's a bit counter-intuitive, but `:first-child` literally means first child **of the parent**, not **of the type, of the parent**, so the only thing that matches `:first-child` in your code is `<div class="someRandomDiv"></div>`.

With `.block:first-child` you're saying elements that have a class of `block` **and** are the first child of their parent, it's not saying "the first one with class `block`"...they're independent selectors and don't overlap here.  So, there are no matches since no element matches both conditions, that make more sense?

It won't support all browsers, but you could use [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) or javascript to do what you want, for example in jQuery it would be:

```
$("#main .block:first").css({ border: '1px solid red' });
```

Comment: An alternative possible solution to this is to wrap your .block divs in their own container element.

Comment: yes makes good sense.  Thanks Nick.  I guess I will just go with the jQuery route for now.